# How to show an update form while keeping the original data in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django Forms to do some updating work. For example, I write a `FilmForm` to present a film information form:

```
class FilmForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    director = forms.CharField()
    release_year = forms.DateField()
    ......(many other infos)
```

And I create and save a model instance using the form. Next time I want to modify only one info, like 'director', and update the model info using the `FilmForm`.

```
def FilmUpdate(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = FilmForm()
        return render(request,'film_update.html', {'form':form})
```

but when the form show up, the html inputs are all blank,and have to input all the original data again while the only item I want modify is just 'director'. So how to present the update form with the original data keeping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def FilmUpdate(request,pk):
    instance = Film.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FilmForm(instance=instance, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        ...
    else:
        form = FilmForm(instance=instance)
        return render(request,'film_update.html', {'form':form})
```

you should pass `instance` arg to `FilmForm`

Comment: Remember to add it in the POST block as well, otherwise it will create a new film each time.